# How to handle NSDecimalNumber using Parse.com?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsdecimalnumber

I'm using Parse.com to build my app and I need to use `NSDecimalNumber` since my app needs to handle money calculations. I understand that Parse stores Numbers and then retrieves them as `NSNumber`. So my question is, is there a way to change the getter of the property of the `PFObjects` that use `NSDecimalNumber` to make it return an `NSDecimalNumber` instead of a `NSNumber`? I'm using `PFObject` subclasses and I'm confused because of the use of the `@dynamic` definition prevents me from overriding the getter method.

If not, what is the correct approach to handle this situation? I really don't want to be converting those numbers every time I access those properties.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `-[NSNumber decimalValue]` return what you expect?

Comment: It does, but I would have to convert it every time I access the property. It would be much cleaner and maintainable to have the property of the object return an NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: Have you checked that the object is not already, in fact, a `NSDecimalNumber`, since it's a subclass of `NSNumber`?

Comment: Yes, in fact it's crashing my app because it doesn't recognise messages sent to it that correspond to the `NSDecimalNumber` class. When I debugged it it appeared as `NSNumber`. Thanks.

Comment: Override the getter for the property in a custom category extension of the class.  Have it always return a  NSDecimalNumber.  @dynamic shouldn't matter (and should be unnecessary in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

This was a nightmare for me, too! If you don't convert the `NSNumber` to an `NSDecimal`, and then to an `NSDecimalNumber`, you end up getting wonderful errors like:

> [__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

To fix it, you can inspect the property attributes to see what type Parse.com *should* be returning, and return a real `NSDecimalNumber` in the getter.

Paste this in your implementation of the PFObject subclass:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id object = [super objectForKey:key];

    // Get property attributes
    objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([self class], [key UTF8String]);
    NSString *attributes = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];

    // Ensure decimal numbers are returned correctly
    if ([attributes rangeOfString:@"NSDecimalNumber"].location != NSNotFound) {
        if (object != nil) {
            return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[object decimalValue]];
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

I was also having trouble setting NaN with Parse.com (i.e. it crashes), so I also now overwrite the setter like so:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // Skip decimal numbers which are NaN
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]] && [object isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]]) {
        return [self removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    [super setObject:object forKey:key];
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've since realized that storing NSDecimalNumbers on Parse doesn't actually store decimal numbers - it stores floats! So the best way to maintain accuracy is to save decimal numbers as `NSString` values on Parse, and re-interpret them on the way back.

The code above works exceedingly well if we swap two things:

In `objectForKey:`:

```
    // Ensure decimal numbers are returned correctly
    if ([attributes rangeOfString:@"NSDecimalNumber"].location != NSNotFound) {
        if (object != nil) {
            return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:object];
        }
    }
```

And in `setObject:forKey:`

```
    // Save decimal numbers as strings
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        return [super setObject:[object stringValue] forKey:key];
    }
```